# BizTalk Xml Assembler HRESULT 80131941

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, xsd-validation, biztalk-2013

I'm using BizTalk 2013 R2. I have an input file that need to be disassembled :

```
<Root xmlns="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schEnveloppe">
  <DOC xmlns="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument">
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Description>Description 001</Description>
  </DOC>
  <DOC xmlns="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument">
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Description>Description 002</Description>
  </DOC>
  <DOC xmlns="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument">
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Description>Description 003</Description>
  </DOC>
</Root>
```

Here is my enveloppe schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schEnveloppe" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schEnveloppe" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation=".\schDocument.xsd" namespace="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument" />
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
      <b:references>
        <b:reference targetNamespace="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument" />
      </b:references>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='Root' and namespace-uri()='http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schEnveloppe']" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ns0:DOC" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here is my document schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="DOC">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The disassembling stage with `XmlDasm` works well, and my enveloppe schema file validate with xml input file instance. My problem is to reassemble the disassembled files (with 1 or more instances), with the same schema files. So here is my disassembled file :

```
<DOC xmlns="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Description>Description 001</Description>
</DOC>
```

Here is the command :

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\SDK\Utilities\PipelineTools\XmlAsm.exe" ..\Xml\DOC1.xml -es ..\Schemas\schEnveloppe.xsd -ds ..\Schemas\schDocument.xsd -c
```

And the error message :

```
Error
Source:         XML assembler
Message:        The 'http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schDocument:DOC' element is not declared.
HRESULT:        80131941
```

I think that my problem is in my schemas, but all sample files validates with all schemas.

Unfortunately, the documentation is poor about xmlasm. Any idea ?

Comment: Well, does it work when running in BizTalk Server?  No one uses the pipeline test tools, seriously.

Comment: No it doesn't work in BizTalk Server. I'm using it in a correleted orchestration by calling `Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.XLANGPipelineManager.ExecuteSendPipeline` with `Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.SendPipelineInputMessages`. Here I want to isolate my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use the same enveloppe schema for disassembler and assembler. The schema shown in the question is correct for disassembling, but for assembling, here is the shema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schEnveloppe" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schEnveloppe" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='Root' and namespace-uri()='http://Test.XmlDasmAsm.BIZ.Schemas.schEnveloppe']" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```